# Access to requested resource is denied on AWS

Tags: amazon-product-api, aws-sts

I am trying to hit the amazon SP-API endpoint. When I am hitting the API endpoint, I am always getting an error 403 Forbidden with the message Access to the requested resource is denied.

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Access to requested resource is denied.",
            "code": "Unauthorized",
            "details": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Steps I did:

- I have created the IAM user, IAM role, and IAM policies.
- I have created the seller account and developer account as well.
- I am using the role ARN in my seller central app.

Using the access token to sign the API request.